# Monorepo for multiple projects using multiple languages

Tags: software-development, git

In a project of mine I have multiple, independent software components.

At the moment, the situation looks like this:

```
root/
    web_scraping/
    rest_api/
    migrations/
    script.py
```

`web_scraping/` is a python project built with [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). I use it to crawl a website and scrape some data that I store in a Redis queue.

`rest_api/` is a Flask app + REST API built with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/) and [Flask-RESTPlus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I also use [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create [Alembic](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/) migration scripts to upgrade/downgrade a PostgreSQL database to a specific revision.

`migrations/` contains the database migrations. Since the database could be used from other components than the Flask app, I think it's better to leave this migration repository in the `root` directory.

`script.py` is a python script thtat I use to process the items stored in Redis and insert them in PostgreSQL.

This scenario is already a bit challenging, because I need different python environments for the different components. E.g. A python 3.6 virtual environment is fine for the Flask app + REST API, but for the web scraping component I have to use a conda environment (because of scrapy and its dependency on [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)).

I plan to add a GraphQL API built in Javascript (I still have to decide between [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server) and [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-yoga/)) and a React frontend which can consume either the REST API and/or the GraphQL API.

So in the end the entire project will look like this:

```
root/
    web_scraping/
    rest_api/
    migrations/
    script.py
    graphql_api/
    frontend/
```

My first thought was to create one repo for each software component, but I keep reading [good stuff](https://www.drmaciver.com/2016/10/why-you-should-use-a-single-repository-for-all-your-companys-projects/) about the `monorepo` and decided to give it a try.

I know that for Javascript projects one could use [Lerna](http://samhogy.co.uk/2018/04/moving-to-a-monorepo.html). And for Python projects there should be [Pants](https://www.pantsbuild.org/index.html), as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/building-a-python-monorepo-for-fast-reliable-development-be763781f67).

My question is, what to do when multiple languages (Python, Javascript) are involved?

Comment: Very interesting question. I have wondering that myself for our projects. Hope you can share what you ended up doing.